# Proof of proportions in proportion by composition and decomposition?

Tags: proof-writing

What is the proof that $\frac{a+b}{a-b}=\frac{c+d}{c-d}$ given that $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$ Here's what I've got so far:

$$\begin{array}{l} 
\text{Statements} &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& \text{Reasons} \\\\ 
\ \text{1.} \frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& \text{1. given} \\ \\
\ \text{2.} \frac{a+b}{b} = \frac{c+d}{d} &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& \text{2. addition transformation}\\
\end{array}$$

After this, I'm not really sure how to get the denominators to a-b and c-d, respectively.

Comment: Oh dear.  Two-column proofs.  Takes me back to high school geometry.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for the reason for 2. I'd write '*add one*'.

Similarly, we can have 3. $\displaystyle\frac{a-b}b=\frac{c-d}d$. Then divide equation 2. by equation 3. 
(You have to separately handle the cases when any denominator would become zero.)